# Registered post type not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create a Custom post type in Wordpress and I'm actually stuck at this , because its not working and I don't know why.

I copied the Custom post type code from here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates

And this is the code i added in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
function create_posttype() {
register_post_type( 'product',
        array( 
             'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
              ),
             'public' => true,
             'capability_type' => 'post',
             'hierarchical' => false,
             'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'page-attributes'), 
             'has_archive' => true,
             'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
             )
       );
}
```

and then i used this code below to create a new post:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $my_title ),
  'post_content'  => $my_content,
  'post_status'   => 'inherit',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_type'   => 'product',
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

**Then i tried to access it the link in the url, but i got a 404 page not found error !**

Please any one know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using pretty permalinks?

Go to Permalinks -> Update.

Comment: Most probably it's a cache issue. Try this to flush permalink cache: `global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();`

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work. thanks

Comment: What you can see post in backend using wp_insert_post($my_post) ?

Comment: Change post status publish instead inherit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function ProductPostType() {
register_post_type( 'product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Product' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'product' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => 'themes',
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product'),
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
      'description' => 'Custom Theme Posts',
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'ProductPostType' );
```

Just paste this code in function.php

Comment: Hi, my problem is that when i manually create a new post, It is not accessible via the Url, But Only when i add product post from admin. That works

Comment: Okey. Go to this URL (yourdomain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php) and in the "common settings" click on "Post name" and click on save changes.
if "Post name" is already selected then just for refresh permalinks, click on "plain" option and again select "Post name" and save the settings. Your custom post type links will be work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super simple trick that may or may not work for you.

1. In the WP-Backend, locate `Settings` and click on the `Permalinks` menu.
2. On the Permalinks Settings Page, simply choose `Plain`... and save the Changes.
3. Go to the Front-End and reload your Plugin to see if your Plugin now functions but without SEO-Friendly URL.
4. Whether it works or not; just go back to the Permalinks Settings & change back to `Day and name`. Save and try it out again....

Comment: Thanks. It did't work though, I guess the real problem am having is wp_insert_post not working well with Custom Post Types. I probably do it some other way.